# When to upgrade to Joomla 3

Tags: joomla-3.x

I've seen a number of posts [here](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/160/when-to-move-to-a-new-major-release) and in Joomla's [docs](http://docs.joomla.org/Joomla_3_FAQ) about upgrading. I'd like to upgrade to Joomla 3.3. But have seen conflicting posts of 3.4 [coming](http://developer.joomla.org/news/583-announcing-joomla-cms-3-4.html).

I'm on Joomla 2.5. My questions:

1. EOL for Joomla 2.5 says Dec 2014. Does that still apply?
2. I do want to take advantage of some features on J3 but I have no urgency (depending on #1). Do I wait for 3.4 or do I start with 3.3? Keeping in mind I don't want to mess with something that is working great right now.
3. When is 3.4 coming out? If at all?
4. I've got a ton of custom components and plug-ins. I used to have a link that showed me some differences when updating these from J2->J3. Anyone know of a list showing things that are deprecated or replaced?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes, the EOL will still apply, meaning Joomla 2.5 as a CMS will no longer be supported. Some extension and template developers may carry on supporting it for longer as there will be a hellish amount of people still on J2.5.
2. Personally I would probably wait for 3.4, however you may want to take a  backup your site, put it on a localhost or subdomain, migrate to J3.3 then when 3.4 is released, it will be a simple 1 click update with no code changes required.
3. I'm not sure on the exact release date of 3.4 as there always seem to be delays with releases these days. The stable released should have been out 2 months ago so I've no idea what is going on. Most likely some last bug fixes or additional features being added.
4. There is a documentation page that  shows the differences for J3.x: http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3_and_Joomla_Platform_12.2

Sorry there isnt as much detail in this as you may need, however I'm abroad and on the mobile, but hope this helps.

Comment: 3.4 will be 1 click from 3.3. Only major branches have breaking changes so op should upgrade sooner rather than later. Most extensions for 2.5 work with 3 but always best to test first on a local copy

Answer (score 4):

As of now Joomla 3.3.x is recommended for all new installs, as you currently have a Joomla 2.5.x site (I'm assuming it will be 2.5.24), you could start planning for an upgrade to 3.3.x

Joomla 2.5.x End of life is December 31st, 2014, this date is set and will remain as the end of life for this release.

Joomla 3.3.x end of life will be once 3.4 is released. Currently the release date of 3.4 is September 15th 2014.

There is alot of changes between 2.5.x and 3.3.x, so you'd need to thoroughly test your extensions and custom components to ensure they are compatible with 3.x

As for the upgrade type, from 2.5, it is a one-click update of the core to 3.x

Check this for the Joomla Roadmap http://developer.joomla.org/cms/roadmap.html